# Kalman filters best practices

Tags: time-series, algorithms, kalman-filter

**Setup**

I finished watched [Quantopian's Lecture on Kalman Filters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RxIdLu18SsE) and went through the [notebook](https://www.quantopian.com/posts/quantopian-lecture-series-kalman-filters).

For those who want to learn more, I found the following links extremely useful:

- [Concept](http://www.bzarg.com/p/how-a-kalman-filter-works-in-pictures/)
- [Equations](http://greg.czerniak.info/guides/kalman1/)
- [Beta Example](http://www.thealgoengineer.com/2014/online_linear_regression_kalman_filter/)
- [Numerical Example](http://bilgin.esme.org/BitsBytes/KalmanFilterforDummies.aspx)
- [A Textbook](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~tracker/media/pdf/SIGGRAPH2001_CoursePack_08.pdf)
- [An IPython Textbook](https://github.com/rlabbe/Kalman-and-Bayesian-Filters-in-Python/blob/master/01-g-h-filter.ipynb)

The Python library that is being used is [pykalman](https://github.com/pykalman/pykalman).

**The code**

In the Quantopian notebook, the meat of the code is here:

```
start = '2012-01-01'
end = '2015-01-01'
y = get_pricing('AMZN', fields='price', start_date=start, end_date=end)
x = get_pricing('SPY', fields='price', start_date=start, end_date=end)

delta = 1e-3
trans_cov = delta / (1 - delta) * np.eye(2) # How much random walk wiggles
obs_mat = np.expand_dims(np.vstack([[x], [np.ones(len(x))]]).T, axis=1)

kf = KalmanFilter(n_dim_obs=1, n_dim_state=2, # y is 1-dimensional, (alpha, beta) is 2-dimensional
                  initial_state_mean=[0,0],
                  initial_state_covariance=np.ones((2, 2)),
                  transition_matrices=np.eye(2),
                  observation_matrices=obs_mat,
                  observation_covariance=2,
                  transition_covariance=trans_cov)

# Use the observations y to get running estimates and errors for the state parameters
state_means, state_covs = kf.filter(y.values)
```

**Question 1**: How to pick delta? Why delta / (1 - delta) * np.eye(2)?

Where does a delta of 1e-3 come from? And why not just do:

```
trans_cov = delta * np.eye(2) # How much random walk wiggles
```

Perhaps this is something that must be optimized using some cross-validation, although I'm not sure what metric to use. If anyone has any insight, would greatly appreciate it.

**Question 2**: How is observation_covariance = 2 decided?

I understand we're talk abouting prices here, and $2 move for a stock 'feels' like a good estimate for the variance of the price of Amazon, but is there a better way to select this rather than gut?

**Question 3**: Why is this approach better than just doing some rolling beta?

At the end of the day, to do some rolling beta you must decide what the lookback window is?

I understand the appeal of Kalman because you don't decide the lookback window, but you do need to decide transition_covariance? And changing this can have the same effect as increasing/decreasing your lookback window.

**Question 4**: Best practices

Are there best practices that I should be aware of? The only thing I can find was [this](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-determine-the-measurement-noise-in-Kalman-Filter-model) on Quora.

---

Any help would greatly be appreciated. Feel free to leave me a comment if you have any questions for me.

Comment: I also asked this question here. There are a few responses. https://www.quantopian.com/posts/kalman-filters-best-practices?utm_campaign=kalman-filters-best-practices